# Megaware Raid 10

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, lsi, megaraid

I have 22 disks and would like to create a Raid 10. Unfortunately my raid controller (MegaRAID SAS 9260-8i) is only capable to handle 8 arrays within a RAID 10. Because of that I could only use 16 disks in a 2 disks per array configuration. I've figured out that it would be possible to use 2 arrays with 10 disks each:

```
MegaCli -CfgSpanAdd -r10 -Array0[20:2,20:3,20:4,20:5,20:6,20:7,20:8,20:9,20:10,20:11] -Array1[28:1,28:2,28:3,28:4,28:5,28:6,28:7,28:8,28:9,28:10,28:11,28:12] Direct WB -a0
```

After reading through the manual for hours I am not sure anymore if this increases the risk of data lost. Could you comment on this? Is there any RAID10 configuration or a similar RAID level that would allow me to use all 22 disks?

Comment: Get a better RAID controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err, I think you're creating them wrong. The controller can handle up to 128 drives.

You should be creating one big RAID10, not doing individual mirrors.

Try using something like:

```
megacli -CfgLdAdd -r1 '['$(seq -f '?:%g' -s, 0 21)']' WB ADRA NoCachedBadBBU -a0
```

Comment: megacli -CfgLdAdd is for RAID 0|1|5|6 according to docs.
This is what I am doing currently: `MegaCli -CfgSpanAdd -r10 -Array0[20:2,20:3,20:4,20:5,20:6,20:7,20:8,20:9,20:10,20:11] -Array1[28:3,28:4,28:5,28:6,28:7,28:8,28:9,28:10,28:11,28:12] Direct WB -a0`

Comment: The `-r1` parameter in my command above will actually create a RAID10 array. Try it.